# How To Split Array Increment By 5 and Assign it to Another Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array variable that have keys from [0] to [1000].

example:

```
$data = Array
(
    [0] => <td>xxxx</td>
    [1] => <td>xxxx</td>
    [2] => <td>xxxx</td>
    [3] => <td>xxxx</td>
    [4] => <td>1234</td>
    [5] => <td>1233</td>
    [6] => <td>1244</td>
    [7] => <td>3218</td>
    [8] => <td>xxxx</td>
    [9] => <td>xxxx</td>
    [10] => <td>xxxx</td>
)
```

What I want is to make an array with HTML tags `<tr>` after 5 increment with `</tr>` as the closed tags in value.

I have tried this code but still not working:

```
for($i = 0;$i <= 20; $i++) {
    if($i % 5 == 0){
    $x[] = '<tr>' . $data[$i] . '</tr>';
    }
}
```

The result is like this:

```
 $x = Array
(
    [0] => <tr><td>xxxx</td></tr>
    [1] => <tr><td>1233</td></tr>
    [2] => <tr></tr>
    [3] => <tr></tr>
    [4] => <tr></tr>
)
```

What I want is something like this:

```
    $x = Array
    (
        [0] => <tr><td>xxxx</td><td>xxxx</td><td>xxxx</td><td>xxxx</td><td>1234</td></tr>
        [1] => <tr><td>1233</td><td>1244</td><td>3218</td><td>xxxx</td><td>xxxx</td></tr>
        [2] => <tr></tr>
        [3] => <tr></tr>
        [4] => <tr></tr>
    )
```

I think I'm really close to the solution, but still confuse until now. Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and then you can `implode` the resulted chunks using `</td><td>` glue:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 5);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo implode('</td><td>', $chunk);
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Also, if your data already contains the `td` tags, then you can simply put an empty string as glue:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 5);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo implode('', $chunk);
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Instead of outputing you can store the result to a variable:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 5);
$x = [];

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $x[] = '<tr>' . implode('', $chunk) . '</tr>';
}

$x = array_merge($x, array_fill(0, 5 - count($chunks), '<tr></tr>'));

var_dump($x);
```

Comment: So what's the hard part in storing it to `$x` instead of outputing it?

Comment: The hard part is to make increment 5 key + 5 value of `$data` into one by one of `$x` array. I have post the example of the result of **what I want**. By the way, thanks for answering this.

Comment: Take a look again at the updated answer.. the last update should be the right one

Answer (score 0):

```
$flg=0;
$x[$flg]="<tr>"; 
for($i = 0;$i <= 20; $i++) {
$x[$flg].=$data[$i];
if($i+1 % 5 == 0){
$x[$flg] .= '</tr><tr>';
$flg++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = "";

for($i = 0;$i <= 20; $i++) {
     $array = $array .  $data[$i] ;
    if($i % 5 == 0){
       $x[] = '<tr>' . $array . '</tr>';
       $array = "";
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: got it, <td> is coming with the data, so no need to repeat in array, check now

Answer (score 0):

You can build a supplementary array with `array_chunk`, if you don't mind that it is an extra operation consuming *O(n)* time and *O(n)* memory.

Another approach is to store the cells into a temporary variable. When the number of items becomes divisible by 5, store the contents of the variable into `$x` and reset the temporary variable, e.g.:

```
$row = [];
foreach ($a as $i => $cell) {
  if ($i && $i % 5 == 0) {
    $x[] = '<tr>' . implode('', $row) . '</tr>';
    $row = [];
  }

  $row[] = $cell;
}

if ($row) {
  $x[] = '<tr>' . implode('', $row) . '</tr>';
}
```

If you want equal number of cells in each row, use `array_pad` in the last block (after the loop), e.g.:

```
if (count($row) < 5) {
  $row = array_pad($row, 5, '<td></td>');
}
```

Comment: Sory, but seems this in not I wanted. I just want to 5 key become one key of `$x` with 5 value from 5 key (`$data`) stick in that one key.